# render vs pre-render javascript canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, canvas, render

I test better method to draw many "many" object with javascript canvas HTML5.

Results obtained by this demo [demo performance on jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/render-vs-prerender) are very impressive. But I want done my own test.

My direct render version:

```
class myClass extends subclass{
    constructor(context,pX,pY,sX,sY,round,color) {
        //...
        //processing 
        //...       
    }

    drawObj(decX,decY,zoom){
        this.roundRect(this.p_ctx, decX+this.p_pX*zoom, decY+this.p_pY*zoom, this.p_sX*zoom, this.p_sY*zoom, this.p_round*zoom, true, false,this.p_color);
    }
    roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke,color) {
        //...
        //trace round rectangle on the ctx canvas
    }
}
```

And my pre-render version:

```
class myClass extends subclass{
    constructor(context,pX,pY,sX,sY,round,color) {
        //...
        //processing 
        //...       

        //trace and save drawing in local canvas
        this.p_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.p_canvas.width = this.p_sX;
        this.p_canvas.height = this.p_sY;
        this.p_ctx_local = this.p_canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.roundRect(this.p_ctx_local, 0,0, this.p_sX, this.p_sY, this.p_round, true, false,this.p_color);

    }

    drawObj(decX,decY,zoom){
        this.p_ctx.drawImage(this.p_canvas, this.p_pX*zoom+decX,this.p_pY*zoom+decY,this.p_sX*zoom,this.p_sY*zoom );        
    }
    roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke,color) {
        //...
        //trace round rectangle on the ctx canvas
    }
}
```

My test consist in draw 1000 myClass objects by calling drawObj function. I do several loop to have a stable results.

My results:

***On desktop (Chrome) : 65ms render / 61ms pre-render***

***On mobile (Chrome nexus 6) : 85ms render / 90ms pre-render***

My obtained results shows that is not interesting to use pre-render because they need big ressources in initialization, whereas direct-render have close results as pre-render but is more easy to use.

I don't understand why my result are different than jsPerf (maybe because I draw different context).

Where is my error?